# Couldn't find file menu in Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My OS is ubuntu 14.04, ROS indigo, the version of Gazebo is 2.2.3 and I follow the tutorials in http://learn.turtlebot.com/.
When I learned to edit map in Gazebo, I couldn't find the file menu.
How can I get file menu back or is there other ways to save map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232897/couldn%27t-find-file-menu-in-gazebo/) by [ROS_learner](https://answers.ros.org/users/26701/ros_learner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally find it.
As in http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_b&tut=guided_b2, (NOTE: Some Linux desktops hide application menus. If you don't see the menus, move your cursor to the top of the application window, and the menus should appear. ). Finally, I maximize the Gazebo window, and put the cursor to the top, GET IT!

---

Originally posted by [ROS_learner](https://answers.ros.org/users/26701/ros_learner/) with karma: 16 on 2016-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0